# Pulling values from CIM - authorize.net

Tags: php, xml, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I've got my script worked out to grab information from the CIM:

```
$content = 
  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" .
  "<getCustomerProfileRequest xmlns=\"AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd\">" .
  merchantAuthenticationBlock().
  "<customerProfileId>$cid</customerProfileId>" .
  "</getCustomerProfileRequest>";

$response = send_xml_request($content);
$parsedresponse = parse_api_response($response);
```

So how, now, do I write the returned value to a variable?

I've tried:

```
$customerPaymentProfileId = $parsedresponse->customerPaymentProfileId;
$customerShippingAddressId = $parsedresponse->customerShippingAddressId;
```

But this returns the variables empty. I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the structure of `$parsedresponse` do either `print_r($parsedresponse)` or `var_dump($parsedresponse)`. From there you can see how the array is structured and get your values from there.

FYI, the payment profiles are in an array so you will need to loop through them to get their values. Assuming `parsedresponse` is the root XML node you can get them like this:

```
foreach ($parsedresponse->profile->paymentProfiles as $profile)
{
    echo $profile->customerPaymentProfileId;
}
```

FYI, this is a sample array structure for this response (From the [AuthnetXML](https://github.com/stymiee/Authorize.Net-XML) Sample Code. *I am the author of this library*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<getCustomerProfileResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
  <messages>
    <resultCode>Ok</resultCode>
    <message>
      <code>I00001</code>
      <text>Successful.</text>
    </message>
  </messages>
  <profile>
    <merchantCustomerId>12345</merchantCustomerId>
    <email>user@example.com</email>
    <customerProfileId>5427896</customerProfileId>
    <paymentProfiles>
      <billTo>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>Smith</lastName>
        <address>123 Main Street</address>
        <city>Townsville</city>
        <state>NJ</state>
        <zip>12345</zip>
        <phoneNumber>800-555-1234</phoneNumber>
      </billTo>
      <customerPaymentProfileId>4796541</customerPaymentProfileId>
      <payment>
        <creditCard>
          <cardNumber>XXXX1111</cardNumber>
          <expirationDate>XXXX</expirationDate>
        </creditCard>
      </payment>
    </paymentProfiles>
    <paymentProfiles>
      <billTo>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>Doe</lastName>
        <company/>
        <address>123 Main St.</address>
        <city>Bellevue</city>
        <state>WA</state>
        <zip>98004</zip>
        <country>USA</country>
        <phoneNumber>800-555-1234</phoneNumber>
        <faxNumber>800-555-1234</faxNumber>
      </billTo>
      <customerPaymentProfileId>4796585</customerPaymentProfileId>
      <payment>
        <creditCard>
          <cardNumber>XXXX1111</cardNumber>
          <expirationDate>XXXX</expirationDate>
        </creditCard>
      </payment>
    </paymentProfiles>
    <shipToList>
      <firstName>John</firstName>
      <lastName>Smith</lastName>
      <address>123 Main Street</address>
      <city>Townsville</city>
      <state>NJ</state>
      <zip>12345</zip>
      <phoneNumber>800-555-1234</phoneNumber>
      <customerAddressId>4907537</customerAddressId>
    </shipToList>
    <shipToList>
      <firstName>John</firstName>
      <lastName>Doe</lastName>
      <company/>
      <address>123 Main St.</address>
      <city>Bellevue</city>
      <state>WA</state>
      <zip>98004</zip>
      <country>USA</country>
      <phoneNumber>800-555-1234</phoneNumber>
      <faxNumber>800-555-1234</faxNumber>
      <customerAddressId>4907591</customerAddressId>
    </shipToList>
  </profile>
</getCustomerProfileResponse>
```

Comment: That did it, John!

`$var = $parsedresponse->profile->paymentProfiles->customerPaymentProfileId;

echo $var;`

This will assign the payment profile ID of the requested customer to a variable which can then be used for various things. 

You, sir, are the man!